# How do I keep Laravel Blade from stripping out alphanumeric strings?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an ID field on my model that consists of alphanumeric strings like 6f7fb019-1a57-4beb-916a-8605868c19a2

In Blade I try `{{ $var->ID }}`

Blade strips out most of this string, even when I wrap it in `{!! !!}`

However when I wrap the literal string in double quotes like `{{ " 6f7fb019-1a57-4beb-916a-8605868c19a2" }}` all is well.

blade template code:

```
    @foreach($work_requests as $work_request)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{$work_request->ID}}</th>
            <td>{{$work_request->STATUS}}</td>
            <td>{{$work_request->created}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

raw model from `dd`

```
    #attributes: array:4 [▼
      "ID" => "6f7fb019-1a57-4beb-916a-8605868c19a2"
      "JSON" => ""
      "STATUS" => " [ CONFIDENTIAL ] "
      "created" => 1550623543
    ]
```

from controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $work_requests = WorkRequest::orderby('created','desc')->paginate(25);
    dd($work_requests);
    return view('workrequests.index')->with('work_requests',$work_requests);
}
```

### FURTHER EXPLANATION

So for these values I get the corresponding result printed:

- 6f7fb019-1a57-4beb-916a-8605868c19a2 returns 6
- c904b27a-9b85-4782-a2de-deea0b9bbf18 returns 0
- 53da0384-3a34-413c-bb73-b3e7b1d589ef returns 53
- 86dd13d5-dd90-4734-9258-fba6742dd574 returns 86

Comment: Shouldn't happen, can you please share your code.

Comment: Try this `return view('workrequests.index')->with('work_requests',compact($work_requests));`

Comment: @ShoaibRaza then I lose pagination

Comment: Can you show what the html output (page source from browser) looks like? What you're describing shouldn't be possible unless there is something else happening

Comment: please see "further explanation" above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with compact, but use it on the variable name (be careful with the syntax):

```
return view('workrequests.index', compact ('work_requests'));
```

For the numbers coming out of blade - this is possibly because, by default, the primary key in Laravel is cast as `int` like:

```
(int) "6f7fb019-1a57-4beb-916a-8605868c19a2" == 6
```

It is still a string, but if you call it via the model's id, it goes through the __get() method, and becomes an int.  You can tell Laravel to make sure it is a string by [casting it in the model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting):

`protected $casts = ['id' => 'string']`;

You can also go directly to the id function and tell Laravel not to increment, which might help more precisely in your case than the `$casts` variable:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

HTH

Comment: this preserves pagination, but doesn't fix the issue. nice catch. please see where i've added "further explanation"

Comment: Oh!  That helps - see edited answer - perhaps that will help.

Comment: `$casts` was it! see https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting for details.

Comment: For the model key, casting with `$keyType = 'string';` instead of `$casts` is preferred. See Eloquent docs about primary keys.